# Returning different state of Discriminate union based upon string input in pattern match (F#)

Tags: types, f#, pattern-matching, discriminated-union

```
type ColType = I of int | S of string | F of float
```

I know that you cannot return a different type from a pattern match which is why I made this type in the first place for a parser I am creating. However with this code:

```
 //create i coltype
    let m (x : int) : ColType =
        ColType.I x
    //create f coltype
    let n (x : float) : ColType = 
        ColType.F x
    //create s coltype
    let b (x : string) : ColType = 
        ColType.S x    

    let pColType =

        let innerFn (charList : char list) = 

            let i = String(List.toArray charList)
            match i with   
            | "int"  -> m
            | "float" ->  n
            | "string" -> b

        many1 parseLowercase |>> innerFn
```

It will still give me an error in the pColType function despite m, n and b returning the same type.

code such as parseLowercase etc is just code to get a string, this is functioning as intended, the problem is the return value not being the same despite all being coltype? (altough different states of it).

Comment: Don't have time for a full answer right now, but the type of a function includes all its inputs. `m`, `n` and `b` are of three different types: `int -> ColType`, `float -> ColType`, and `string -> ColType`. So your `match i with` expression is returning three different types, and that's not allowed.

Comment: The problem is that all branches of a `match` must have the same type, and in your case these branches are `m : int -> ColType`, `n : float -> ColType`, and `b : string -> ColType`. They _return_ the same type, but they need to _have_ the same type.

Answer (score 1):

Like rmunn and Romanov mentioned your 3 functions are of different type. You can make them return a single type for instance `obj -> ColType` using `box` & `unbox`:

```
let pColType =

    let innerFn (charList : char list) = 
        let i = String(List.toArray charList)
        match i with   
        | "int"    -> unbox >> m
        | "float"  -> unbox >> n
        | "string" -> unbox >> b
        |_-> failwithf "error %A" i

    many1 parseLowercase |>> innerFn
```

That requires that you `box` the value before invoking the resulting function.
Since you are building a parser it makes more sense to instead make it return a `string -> ColType`:

```
let pColType =

    let innerFn (charList : char list) = 
        let i = String(List.toArray charList)
        match i with   
        | "int"    -> parseInt    >> m
        | "float"  -> parseFloat  >> n
        | "string" -> parseString >> b
        |_-> failwithf "error %A" i

    many1 parseLowercase |>> innerFn
```